# Control proportions different between runtime and designer

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm currently modifying an existing C# WinForm project. I try to arrange some controls inside a GroupBox. However on runtime, they seem to be aligned differently and the Groupbox has a lot more space. Is there some option checked or is this the standard behavior? Any hints are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is what it looks like, as you can see there is no way except trial and error to arrange the checkboxes. On runtime there is easily enough space to have four colums in one row, in designer i can hardly fit three without having them overlap.

[image: Left - Designer, Right - Runtime]

Comment: Is Groupbox resizes according to its content in runtime?

Comment: thanks for the comment, please check out the screenshot

Comment: @user871784 share the code please

Comment: Is the form resizing anywhere in your code?

Comment: your right Window is bigger so it's maybe some autostrech and your checkboxes doesn't have a fixed position so they also move based on  your strech like your Buttons in your Commands Groupbox

Comment: i also would recomment to search for the name of your groupbox in your Project maybe your predecessor did something with this groupbox at an unexpected code part because such a resizing isn't an normal behavior if you doesn't do anything to the groupbox even if `AutoSize= false;`

Comment: I have the same problem. I know that it is a screen resolution problem but I have searched much, NOTHING HELPED ((

Comment: It seems this is a bug in visual studio. Check this link pls : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/976183/windows-forms-designer-dpi-scaling-problems

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the groupbox to resize according to its content, you should make [GroupBox.AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.autosize.aspx) to `false`.

```
 GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox();
 groupBox.AutoSize= false;
```

Comment: Did u make AutoSize to false?

Comment: It was set to false from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

check to `Size` property, and check if someone change it, for the `checkbox` Location to stay the same in different sizes of the form use `anchor` property and set it to left or left top.

it's basically must be the size, if the `autoSize` is off. check what's the starting size, and the size after the form is shown. it shouldn't be the same, but if it is, you can set it to smaller

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Anchor` property on the checkboxes. Looks like some of them might be anchored to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it applies to these checkboxes, but AutoScaleMode can impact the scaling of a form. Set to None to ensure it doens't get scaled.
[image: AutoScaleMode=None]